# VBA text import with other delimiter "="

Tags: vba, excel, delimiter

I have encountered a problem when trying to import a text file into Excel. I wrote a VBA code which perfectly handles the import with the following semicolon delimiter.

> ;

However, when I try to include other delimiter (In my case equal to) also

> =

It throws me an error.

> The method ' Open Text' for the object 'Workbooks' failed.

Please find attached my sample text file which usually has an extension .cfg

```
Dos-001-Zykl_Date_r(V1.0)=1401174131;27.05.2014 07:02:11;
Dos-002-Zykl_Date_r(V1.0)=1401174225;27.05.2014 07:03:45;
```

and its corresponding VBA code

```
Sub ImportTextFile()
'Imports a text file
Dim vFileName

On Error GoTo ErrorHandle

 vFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename()

'If the user pressed "Cancel" or didn't select a text file,
'exit the procedure.
If vFileName = False Then
   GoTo BeforeExit
End If

'Switch off screen updating for speed.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'We now import the selected text file, and data is
'inserted in a new spreadsheet. If you want to use
'another delimiter, you must change "Semicolon:=True"
'to "Semicolon:=False" and set another delimiter
'(e.g. "Tab") to True.
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=vFileName, _
    Origin:=xlMSDOS, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
    xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=True, _
    Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True, Local:=True

'Just to show how we auto adjust the width of column A.
Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit

BeforeExit:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub
ErrorHandle:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume BeforeExit
End Sub
```

Suggestions, ideas would be really helpful in solving this issue.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In your `Workbooks.OpenText` line change `Semicolon:=True` to `Semicolon:=False` and `Other:=False` to `Other:=True, OtherChar="="`

Comment: @Tom It works. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to include your other criteria. This can handle multiple delimiters.

I've updated this changing `Other:=False` to `Other:=True, OtherChar="="`

```
Sub ImportTextFile()
    'Imports a text file
    Dim vFileName

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandle

     vFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename()

    'If the user pressed "Cancel" or didn't select a text file,
    'exit the procedure.
    If vFileName = False Then
       GoTo BeforeExit
    End If

    'Switch off screen updating for speed.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'We now import the selected text file, and data is
    'inserted in a new spreadsheet. If you want to use
    'another delimiter, you must change "Semicolon:=True"
    'to "Semicolon:=False" and set another delimiter
    '(e.g. "Tab") to True.
    Workbooks.OpenText fileName:=vFileName, _
        Origin:=xlMSDOS, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
        xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=True, _
        Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:="=", _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True, Local:=True

    'Just to show how we auto adjust the width of column A.
    Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit

BeforeExit:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume BeforeExit
End Sub
```